# dynamic row is being disturbed by height increase of first div of md-6

Tags: css

I am making dynamic div of class row divided by two div of md-6  as expected  my result is coming when first div height is small but if it is not the third and forth div position is disturbed

kindly check screen shots in

https://screenshots.firefox.com/Pg5ACKyMlWCQVYx1/localhost
as in screen shot reviews under date 2017-10-25 is my desired result  but the above reviews are mess

my code is

```
<?php
while($row = $getdate->fetch_assoc())
{
        $date = $row['DATE(reviews_date)'];
        $getdatedata = $user->getdatedata($date);



?>
<h4 class="hdg" style="color:#212121;"> <?php echo $date ;?></h4>
<hr style="height:1px;border:none;background-color:#333;" />
<div class = "row">
<?php 
while($rowdata = $getdatedata->fetch_assoc())
{
?>

<div class="col-md-6" style="position: relative;">
    <p>Review # <?php echo $rowdata['reviews_id']; ?>
    </p>
    <p>
    Written by <?php echo  $rowdata['reviews_by']; ?> after counseling with <?php echo  $rowdata['reviews_to']; ?> for <?php echo $rowdata['duration'];?> on issues concerning <?php echo  $rowdata['issue']; ?> .
    </p>
    <br>
    <h5 style="color:#212121;"">
    <?php echo $rowdata['reviews_body'];?>
    </h5>
    <br>
    <div class="w3_agileits_services_grid1">
        <div class="w3_agileits_services_grid1l">
            <img src="<?php echo  $rowdata['coun_image']; ?>" alt=" " class="img-responsive" />
        </div>
        <div class="name">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="courses.html"> <?php echo  $rowdata['reviews_to']; ?> </a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <li><?php echo  $rowdata['coun_degree'];?> </li>
                </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr style="height:1px;border:none;background-color:#333;width:550px;margin-top:100px;">
</div>

<?php 
 }
?>
</div>
<br>
        <?php
    } ?>

enter code here
```

Comment: is my question is unclear ?

Comment: why there is no response